# Error while finding spec for 'fibo.py' (<class 'AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__')

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

I have a module in a `fibo.py` file which has the following functions -

```
#fibonacci numbers module

def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()

def fib2(n): # return Fibonacci series up to n
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

Now when I run the module from the cli python3 as -

```
> python3 -m fibo.py
```

I get the error

```
Error while finding spec for 'fibo.py' (<class 'AttributeError'>:
'module' object has no attribute '__path__')
```

The `__path__` variable has has the current dir . I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

There are two ways you can run a Python 3 script.

1. `python fibo.py`: The argument is the name of the `.py` file.  Dots are part of the filename.
2. `python -m fibo`: The argument is the name of a Python module, without `.py`.  Dots indicate packages; `fibo.py` means "the module `py` in the package `fibo`."

This is a small distinction for a simple script like yours.  But for something bigger or more complex, it has an important effect on the behavior of the `import` statement:

1. The first form will cause `import` to search the directory where the `.py` file lives (and then search various other places including the standard library; see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) for a full list).
2. The second form will make `import` search the *current* directory (and then various other places).

For this reason, under Python 3, the second form is required for most setups which involve packages (rather than just loose modules in a directory), since the parent package of the script may not be importable under the first form, which can cause things to break.

But for a simple script like this, either form is fine.

Comment: well obviously the second form is not fine for a case like this, seeing how it raises an error.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Look closer.  OP put a .py after the name of the module.  Module names are *not* file names.

Comment: @Kevin - thanks. I was adding the .py extension for the module and hence the error, which was entirely misleading for me. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: also seems that we have to use -m option    to pass arguments.......

Comment: I think you just saved me 2 hours of figuring why my Jenkins build fails :) Thanks!

Comment: When you say _and then various other places_ for point 2, does that include also the `sys.path`? What else is included?

Answer (score 15):

These are two different ways to run a python 3 script:

python fibo.py: The argument is the name of the .py file.

python -m fibo: The argument is the name of a Python module, without .py

Comment: Thank you @AMIT SAMOTA I read the answer above, but yours was clear and quick. I reread the first answer and now I understand both.  To other readers, you might be looking for python -m com.mypackage.mypythongfile without the .py bit.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kevin's answer: you should add path to your script folder to PYTHONPATH environment variable to make it work on some OS.