# My long description isn't showing on PyPi?

Tags: python, pypi

I tried having long_description print when I build my wheel, and it prints just fine. But when I upload to PyPi it doesn't show my long description there. Here's my setup.py, hopefully someone can help figure this out.

```
from setuptools import setup
from codecs import open
from os import path

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()
setup(
    name='matchmod',
    version='1.2.1',
    description='Simple Rust-like pattern matching for Python, with some added features',
    long_description=long_description,
    url='https://github.com/AN3223/rustlike-pattern-matching-for-python',
    author='AN3223',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    ],
    keywords='rust rustlang procedural',
    py_modules=['matchmod']
)
```

EDIT: I just realized I'm getting this error when building the wheel `Error while finding module specification for 'setup.py' (AttributeError: module 'setup' has no attribute '__path__')`, not sure what to do to solve this? I tried opening the file this way like the link from yausername suggested but **still got the same error**:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_string

long_description = resource_string(__name__, 'README.rst').decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: There might be a problem becuase of the __file__ attribute
http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs#accessing-package-resources

Comment: Hey @yausername thanks for replying. I tried what the link suggested, prints fine just as before but still has the same issue when I build the wheel. Edited the post to explain further.

Comment: what command are you using to building the wheel?

Comment: python -m setup.py bdist_wheel

Comment: either use `python setup.py bdist_wheel` or `python -m setup bdist_wheel`
as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36230538/3663254)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have made the error go away at least, but the description still isn't showing up on PyPi. I tried uploading using both commands.