# AttributeError: module '' has no attribute '__path__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

I'm having a problem which I have no idea how to further debug.

I have a project with different purposes, making use of Python 3 among other things.
I created a Python package named ***package***.
The package's top-directory is located inside ***myproject/python/***.
In the filesystem, it has the following structure:

```
- /home/myuser/myproject/python
--- package/
------ __init__.py
------ myutil.py
------ sub_package/
---------- __init__.py
---------- sub_sub_package/
-------------- __init__.py
-------------- myscript.py
```

All **__init__.py** files are blank, with the exception of the root one (**package/__init__.py**), which has the following contents:

```
from . import myutil
```

So far so good.
The file **myscript.py** is actually a Python script to run directly.
As it resides inside a package, I am executing it as such:

```
cd /home/myuser/myproject/python
python -m package.sub_package.sub_sub_package.myscript
```

Now the weird part. The script works as expected.
However, after the program finishes, I get the following message:

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 
'package.sub_package.sub_sub_package.myscript.py'
(AttributeError: module 'package.sub_package.sub_sub_package.myscript' 
has no attribute '__path__')
```

I have been searching online but to no avail.
Can't figure out what is causing this message and how to solve it.
I am guessing it is some obscure behavior of Python 3's import handling, but have no clue.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the solution in this thread -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030519/python-tornado-attributeerror-module-test-has-no-attribute-path Cheers

Answer (score 9):

Two ways to run a python 3 script with a filename '`fibo.py`':

The argument is the name of the .py file.

```
python fibo.py
```

The argument is the name of a Python module, without .py

```
python -m fibo
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not have `__init__.py` file in the last directory sub_sub_package

try adding an empty `__init__.py` file there

Comment: I have done that, the behavior appears to be the same.

Comment: this seems similar to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230492/python-error-while-finding-spec-for-fibo-py-class-attributeerror-mod

Comment: Well I had seen that one already. The major concern in the answer of that issue was to use the **-m** flag, which I am doing already.