# Python Tornado AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute '__path__'

Tags: python, path, tornado

I am attempting to just run the `Hello World` code from [Tornado docs](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/index.html)

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Except I am getting an error: `AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute '__path__'`

I am just using IDLE to run `test.py`

I thought this was due to my Windows 10 computer not having Python accessible to `PATH` but even with adding in the python 3.6 to `PATH` I am still getting the same error. Any ideas?

The screenshot is how I added python to `PATH` and I think I got it correct..

[image]

------***EDIT***------

Ill add some screenshots of the errors/tracebacks I am running into. 1st one is the command prompt below when the `test.py` is ran in IDLE 3.6 in Windows 10.

[image]

If there is an import error, I can import Tornado just fine thru IDLE interpreter.
[image]

I also tried running this `hello World` code in IPython 3.7, and I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: Can you give me a tip on how to do a full error trace back?

Comment: Post the full error message that you're getting.

Comment: I added some screenshots

Comment: Odd in Ipython even restarting the kernel & rerunning the code the same error always popped up the loop was running

Comment: The error message is still unclear. Maybe try running `test.py` without `-m` argument.

Comment: That worked... When I removed the -m argument a pop window for Windows Firewall came up where I had to grant Python access... What does the -m argument do?

Comment: If you create an answer, I can hit the green check box. Thank you so :)

Comment: With Tornado would you happen to know how to kill the Python interpreter? A `CNTRL-C` doesn't do anything. Im used to Flask where it would print that the server is running... But nothing pops up in the command Window.. But I am least seeing hello world :)

Comment: I've added an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution:** Run your file without the `-m` argument.

Another solution would be to provide the file name without the `.py` extension:

```
python -m test
```

This will also work.

---

**Explanation:**

The `-m` argument tells Python to run a module (file) present in the Python path. It doesn't take the name of the file, it takes the name of the module. The difference is that the file name contains `.py` suffix, whereas the module name doesn't.

So you can run the `test.py` file like this, too: `python -m test`.

---

**When to use `-m` argument:**

The `-m` argument is there for convenience. For example, if you want to run python's default http server (which comes with python), you'd write this command:

```
python -m http.server
```

This will start the http server for you. The convenience that `-m` argument gives you is that you can write this command from anywhere in your system and python will automatically look for the package called `http` in your the system's `Path`.

Without the `-m` argument, if you wanted to run the http server, you'd have to give it's full path like:

```
python C:\path\to\python\installation\http\server.py
```

So, `-m` argument makes it easy to run modules (files) present in the `Path`.

---

> With Tornado would you happen to know how to kill the Python interpreter? A `CNTRL-C` doesn't do anything.

I use Linux and `Ctrl-C` works fine for me. On Windows you can try `Ctrl-D` or `Ctrl-Z`. Or here are some answers: [Stopping python using ctrl+c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1364173/1925257)