# Pytest "No module named..." issue

Tags: python, import, module, pytest, importerror

So I'm running into issues when I run pytest versus when I invoke the tested module directly. Pytest actually runs fine but I run into issues trying to directly invoke the python file that I'm testing. Here is the basic folder layout:

```
generate
├── generate
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── write_sql.py
│   └── utils.py
└── tests
    └── test_write_sql.py
```

Within both `test_write_sql.py` and `write_sql.py` I'm importing things using the `generate` module like so:

```py
from generate import utils
```

Running `pytest` from the root `generate` folder works fine. But when I try to invoke `write_sql.py` directly from the root `generate` folder I run into the following error:

```bash
root@637572f508b9:~/generate# python3 generate/write_sql.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/generate/generate/write_sql.py", line 5, in <module>
    from generate import utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'generate'
```

My impression was that running Python from the `generate` root folder should add the `generate` subfolder as a module to the system path (due to the included `__init__.py` file). I know if I change the import to `import utils` inside `write_sql.py` then the direct call to `write_sql.py` works but then pytest runs into import errors.

Any ideas as to what import scheme I should use to get both pytest and the direct invocation working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issues with imports, the way i fixed it was setting all the imports so that the code runs. In order to run the tests instead of just calling `pytest` (this runs all tests from the folder where they are located, therefore there will be import error) it should be called from the root directory like this:

`python3 -m pytest`

or

`python -m pytest`

this way it runs all tests from the root directory, and it should not give import errors

Comment: Thank you that did it :) Ended up making all imports (in `generate` and `tests` folders) of the form `from generate import ...`  and ran both the direct invocation and pytest command via `python -m`. This SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230492/error-while-finding-spec-for-fibo-py-class-attributeerror-module-objec) was useful. Magic!